# Android indeterminate progress bar

Tags: java, android, user-interface, progress-bar, progress

I have created the progress bar in the XML code as follows:

```html
     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:indeterminate="true" 
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"  />
```

Resulting in a progress bar which runs through at 100% the whole time. I would like to set it up so a small section of the progress bar is to cycle through over and over, not just have a bar full at 100% the whole time.

**Note:** I don't want this progress bar to actually track any tasks, I just want it to run indefinitely on the screen.

Comment: i believe progress depends on a count, you would have to reset that count over and over till you want the progress bar to work

Comment: you may want to show the code you are using to update the progress bar

Comment: Indeterminate progress bar animates 100% by design. I believe an animated progress bar showing less than 100% would have to be created as a custom View.